# different arithmetic interpolate functions for int and float in AudioResamplerFirProcess.h

Tags: android, audio

Currently I am trying to do some SSE optimization for AudioResamplerDyn which looks only have ARM neon optimization there.

During my implementation,I have a question about interpolate function in AudioResamplerFirProcess.h:

```
template<typename TC, typename TINTERP>
inline
TC interpolate(TC coef_0, TC coef_1, TINTERP lerp)
{
    return lerp * (coef_1 - coef_0) + coef_0;
}

template<>
inline int16_t interpolate<int16_t, uint32_t>(int16_t coef_0, int16_t coef_1, uint32_t lerp)
{   // in some CPU architectures 16b x 16b multiplies are faster.
    return (static_cast<int16_t>(lerp) * static_cast<int16_t>(coef_1 - coef_0) >> 15) + coef_0;
}
```

The code for (int16_t, uint32_t) there confused me since it looks not a implementation for lerp * (coef_1 - coef_0) + coef_0 which will be used for (float, float). If anyone knows why the float and int use a different arithmetic?

Comment: How precisely is this supposed to be used?  Not at all obvious.

Comment: I understood this is because the coefs is represented by Q15 format now.